# Delphi Sydney Object Inspector blanking unexpectedly

Tags: object, delphi, is-empty, inspector, delphi-10.4-sydney

In my new Delphi Sydney the Object Inspector sometimes goes light blue showing no information whether I'm in Design mode or not. [image: image with blue area at right] The image spans two monitors: you see some of the form at the left on monitor 1 which goes up to the right edge of the Projects / Palette windows, to the right you see some of monitor 2 with the light blue blank Object Inspector. I can see its size as it covers other windows on monitor 2 but it is blank and therefore useless to me.

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Mike

Comment: This happens to me too. It's a bug in the IDE. It's not the only one.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand thanks -- what is your best workaround? Use 1 monitor only?

Comment: This is a problem that happens very rarely for me, so I don't have any standard workarounds. If I were you I'd try to provoke the IDE: move panels around, resize the window, restart the IDE (obviously), restore the desktop settings, etc.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand, thanks, I have done that and restart helps but a few minutes later it's back. Just moved up from XE.... what about downgrading to Rio or some previous city version?

Comment: I wouldn't downgrade. Instead, I'd make sure I have the very latest version (10.4.1) and maybe file a bug report at https://quality.embarcadero.com/.

Comment: Filing a bug report at quality.embarcadero.com is the best you can do. Try to find steps which when followed from an IDE start conduce to the bug you see.

Comment: thanks both, I have engaged Embarcadero support and they are trying to help.